# Error while writing a list in reverse order using stack

Tags: python, stack

I wrote this program to print elements in a list in reverse order. It's giving me the correct answer, but it shows another error after the answer.
What's wrong with my code?

Stack Class

```
class Stack:
  def __init__(self):
    self.items=[]

  def isEmpty(self):
    return self.items==[]

  def push(self,data):
    self.items.append(data)

  def size(self):
    return len(Self.items)

  def show(self):
    print (self.items)

  def peek(self):
    return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

  def pop(self):
    assert not self.isEmpty()
    return self.items.pop()
```

Program

```
def reverseOrder():
    lista = [1,4,6,7,8,9]
    s = Stack()

    for i in lista:
        s.push(i)

    while s.isEmpty:
        print(s.pop())

reverseOrder()
```

and following is my output:

```
>>> 
 RESTART: C:/Users/Dil/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Tutorials/reverseOrder.py 
9
8
7
6
4
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dil/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Tutorials/reverseOrder.py", line 35, in <module>
    reverseOrder();
  File "C:/Users/Dil/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Tutorials/reverseOrder.py", line 33, in reverseOrder
    print(s.pop());
  File "C:/Users/Dil/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Tutorials/reverseOrder.py", line 21, in pop
    assert not self.isEmpty()
AssertionError
>>>
```

Comment: `while s.isEmpty` must be `while not s.isEmpty()`. Call your functions! And do not use semicolons.

Comment: No, then it's not giving me the output at all..    There I'm checking a condition. so it should be s.isEmpty only as I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, everything works just as You wrote it :-). `assert` command do as it name says, it asserts some condition. If condition is meet, everything is fine. If it's not, it raises an error. What You need instead of `assert` is:

```
def pop(self):
    if not self.isEmpty():
        return self.items.pop()
```

But, since You already check that list is not empty in `while` loop, You should leave this out, so it should be like:

```
def pop(self):
    return self.items.pop()
```

As others have suggested, instead of

```
while s.isEmpty():
```

You should use

```
while not s.isEmpty():
```

Comment: still it's not giving me the output

Comment: Please check line: `while s.isEmpty:`. You should add parentheses in order to call function.

Answer (score 2):

```
while s.isEmpty():
    print(s.pop())
```

This should be

```
while not s.isEmpty():
    print(s.pop())
```

Remove elements from stack while it is not empty.

Comment: It should be `not s.isEmpty()`.

Comment: yes, the logic is true.. but my program atleast show me the answer. but when i write 'not.isEmpty' it's not showing me any answer...

Comment: Works for me. Did you add the parenthesis after `isEmpty`?